# Convert local + offset time to utc time with python standard library

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.x, python-2.6

I am getting local + offset from a list of filename. I want to convert that string to utc time in python without using dateutil or pytz as these are not available in standard library.

Input : 20180612124500+0300 (local with offset)
Output : 2018-06-12 09:45:00 (utc)

Comment: there is `datetime` in the standard library though

Comment: I am new with python and i don't know how to comvert using datetime as well. It would be very helpful if you provide an example code using input and output provided